# NodeJS gives Cannot find module './parser' error while running Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, npm

I have written a Handlebars template and got it working successfully in the Browser.  As a next step, I want to use the [Handlebars precompiler](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html), which is a NodeJS module.  I downloaded Handlebars for NodeJS and all dependencies, locally (no -g).  But I can't seem to get past this step:

```
c:\node_modules> node
> require("handlebars");
Error: Cannot find module './parser'
    ...
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node_modules\handlebars\lib\handlebars\compiler\base.js:1:80)
    ...
```

I opened base.js, and line 1 looks like:

```
var handlebars = require("./parser");
```

But there is no parser.js in the folder containing base.js ([see folder at github](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/tree/master/lib/handlebars/compiler)), or any parent folder.  The [NPM page for Handlebars](https://npmjs.org/package/handlebars) does not mention any dependency on parser.js that I could find.  I don't know if I missed an obvious step, or if I'm supposed to generate this file.  Any help or ideas?

Comment: why not just install it globally and follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js#precompiling-templates)?
You also have to run handlebars directly from the terminal like `handlebars templatename` and not via the Node REPL

Comment: I'm on an offline network at work (for security reasons), so 'npm install -g handlebars' won't be able to download from npmjs.org.  I had to download the zip from github and manually move it to the offline network.

Comment: Downloading the zip or cloning the git repository will not be sufficient, because the handlebars module needs the following modules to work: 
- benchmark
- dust
- jison
- mocha
- mustache
- optimist
- should
- uglify-js
.
For simplicity reasons: Can you download all the necessary packages on a PC with internet access (so actually just run `npm install` in the handlebars folder) and then just copy the folder with all the modules?

Comment: That wasn't the problem, I had downloaded all the dependant modules.  Trouble is that parser.js does not exist in the github folder I linked in the question.  I did your suggestion on a connected machine and copied the folder, and was able to get parser.js.  If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity reasons: Just download all the necessary packages on a PC with internet access (so actually just run  `npm install` in the handlebars folder) and then just copy the folder with all the modules

Answer (score 0):

if the command 'npm install' didn't work to solve the issue then try this command, which solved my problem as well:

```
yarn add http-parser-js
```